# how to implement timer in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, timer, ctime

I want to call a function of the business class after every 2 hours.
I m not getting any way to implement same in C/C++ without using a while loop.
My problem is that i cannot use while(1) as this does not retun back the control for further execution.

Any pointer in this regards wud be helpful....:)

thnaks

Comment: The answer will depend on what platform you're on.  Linux?  Windows?  Something else?

Comment: Just curious.  What does your program do for 2 hours if it's not already implemented as an event loop?

Comment: I m trying to achieve this on Mac Os X and actually it is a background process so it runs always in backgroung as long as your system is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain C, I would've considered using the `alarm(2)` or `setitimer(2)` functions. Alternatively, spawn a thread and do the waiting from there.

If you decide on the alarm or setitimer routes, bear in mind that you'll need to write signal handlers and may need a dispatch loop to note that it is time to do the periodic maintenance calls, as it's considered bad practise to do quite a few things from within a signal handler.

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) provides [Timers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/timers.html).

Answer (score 0):

For a general solution, you could start a thread, which sends some message to the main thread after 2 hours.

For linux, you could use this:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/alarm

and then handle the SIGALRM signal